# add constant c to each element of specific part of matrix, avoiding loop

Tags: matlab

I have an mxn matrix X of return values, where I want to add a constant term c for each element of the following sub matrix Y of my original matrix X.

```
Y = X(end-4:end,:)
```

Is there a possibility avoiding a loop?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And why can't you do `Y = X(end-4:end,:).+c`?

Comment: `X(end-4:end,:)+c` will add `c` to the given elements of `X`, or `Y = X(end-4:end,:)+c` with leave X as it is and create the "sub matrix" with `c` added to each element, or finally `Y=X;Y(end-4:end,:)+c` will create a copy of `X` with the changes made within it

Comment: oh gosh thanks! too easy that i thought about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate some sample data

```
X = rand(6,6)

X =

   0.9696054   0.7389534   0.7440913   0.2781074   0.0622399   0.0154607
   0.8043438   0.8845991   0.1999374   0.2341657   0.6345166   0.8774855
   0.0092971   0.1108798   0.1118406   0.6249466   0.3932468   0.4050876
   0.6970928   0.1084640   0.0937833   0.8243776   0.7633255   0.0650740
   0.3161001   0.4452197   0.1290970   0.5837050   0.5709813   0.2331514
   0.0739229   0.5626630   0.8300330   0.9590604   0.0852536   0.0225583
```

I do `Y=X` so that that `X` and `Y` will have the same dimensions and it can easily be seen where the addition occured. It's for display purposes, really.

```
   Y=X;
```

Add the constant to the elements you want, element-wise

```
Y(end-4:end,:) = X(end-4:end,:)+4
Y =

   0.969605   0.738953   0.744091   0.278107   0.062240   0.015461
   4.804344   4.884599   4.199937   4.234166   4.634517   4.877485
   4.009297   4.110880   4.111841   4.624947   4.393247   4.405088
   4.697093   4.108464   4.093783   4.824378   4.763326   4.065074
   4.316100   4.445220   4.129097   4.583705   4.570981   4.233151
   4.073923   4.562663   4.830033   4.959060   4.085254   4.022558
```

The relevant elements are now four times larger than they originally were.